# Can one Kafka Producer Class have multiple @EventListener methods?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Im using Spring Kafka and wrote Producer Class

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class Producer {

    private static final String TOPIC = "channels";
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Producer.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    @EventListener(ApplicationStartedEvent.class)
    public void channels_01() throws IOException {

    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationStartedEvent.class)
    public void channels_02()throws IOException {
        
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationStartedEvent.class)
    public void channels_03()throws IOException {
        
    }
}
```

Is it possible to run 3 @Eventlistener annotated methods as producer simutaneouly?
3 methods are sending records to exactly same topic. Will spring container and kafka server recognize them as 3 separate producer clients?

Comment: Your question is unclear. That annotation is for consumers, not producers, but also if you want to process the same event 3 different ways, you should use one listener annotated method with 3 regular non-annotated method calls. Otherwise, you must use different groupIds for each annotation

Comment: @OneCricketeer what I really wanna do is to create 3 producer sending in same message key value format and destination (which is, topic) but from different source each other. I want to run them simultaneously. Actually EventListener annotation is not a significant factor. How can I achieve it?

Comment: You can simply inject/use the same KafkaTemplate and call send method 3 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have three producer clients, then you need to have three `KafkaTemplate` and use a `producerPerThread = true` option of the `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory`:

```
/**
 * Set to true to create a producer per thread instead of singleton that is shared by
 * all clients. Clients <b>must</b> call {@link #closeThreadBoundProducer()} to
 * physically close the producer when it is no longer needed. These producers will not
 * be closed by {@link #destroy()} or {@link #reset()}.
 * @param producerPerThread true for a producer per thread.
 * @since 2.3
 * @see #closeThreadBoundProducer()
 */
public void setProducerPerThread(boolean producerPerThread) {
```

Then you need to ensure that `ApplicationEventMulticaster` is asynchronous. See `SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster`:

```
/**
 * Set a custom executor (typically a {@link org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor})
 * to invoke each listener with.
 * <p>Default is equivalent to {@link org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor},
 * executing all listeners synchronously in the calling thread.
 * <p>Consider specifying an asynchronous task executor here to not block the
 * caller until all listeners have been executed. However, note that asynchronous
 * execution will not participate in the caller's thread context (class loader,
 * transaction association) unless the TaskExecutor explicitly supports this.
 * @see org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor
 * @see org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor
 */
public void setTaskExecutor(@Nullable Executor taskExecutor) {
```

Register a bean with name `applicationEventMulticaster` for it and set a desired `TaskExecutor` to ensure that your `@EventListener` methods are called in parallel.

Comment: what if I need to pass different parameters to each producer client? in this case, each producer thread? I want each producer thread get message records from diffrent url sources.

Comment: We probably need much more info from you what is your goal and you are going to produce that data: I doubt event listener can help somehow since there is no a meaningful context to be able to determine the source for information

Comment: what I want is to crawl live chat logs. For this, I need socket irc connection but document says irc server has buffer limitation which once be exceeded will disconnect connection. So I want to create number of socket connections instead of 1 and want to send this socket to each producer client as parameter whose logic and destination topic is same. From kafka topic, I want to send messages to S3, elaisticsearch and mysql (which Im considerring Mysql Connector or Spark Streaming as middleware)

Comment: So, as I said: just have 3 Kafka templates and call them with respective arguments . You even don’t need to think about different threads: Kafka producer is async. The event listener is fully misleading though: your question turned out to something different …